# What are the mountains visible in these photos?

Tags: identify-this, nepal, mount-everest

My friend claims that Mt. Everest is visible in these pictures

Is it possible to distinguish which one is Mt. Everest, or if it is visible in any one of them?

(Note: the original picture looks better on my computer, but I am not sure if the imgur reupload reduces the quality significantly)

Edit:

The pictures were taken when the plane was flying over Nepal and the pilot specifically announced Mount Everest would be visible outside the window

The mountains depicted are the Himalayas in Nepal, but I would like to know if Mt Everest can be specifically identified in one or all of these pictures; I am hoping Mt Everest has some identifying features which are visible in one of these photoes

Picture 1 and 2 (click for hi-res):
[image] [image]

Picture 3 and 4 (click for hi-res):
[image]  [image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel.

Comment: @JonathanReez The identify-this tag is precisely for this sort of thing (and you'd be amazed at what people have identified!), so IMHO this is on-topic.

Comment: @jpatokal `identify-this` is only relevant for queries where the OP is interested in traveling to the location. Since there's no such question in this scenario, I consider it off-topic.

Comment: then lets just say the OP is interested in travelling there

Comment: I guess the question will suit the `identify-this` tag, if the OP asks about mountains depicted, but not specifically about Mt. Everest.  @user13267 could you provide the flight information as well as date and time?

Comment: this was taken when the plane was flying over Nepal and the pilot specifically announced Mount Everest would be visible outside the window

Comment: The mountains depicted are the Himalayas in Nepal; I just need to know if Mt Everest can be specifically identified in one or all of these pictures

Comment: @user13267 could you provide the flight information as well as date and time (in order to make your request much easier)?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure about those

Comment: most likely it was Thai Airways sometime around January or February

Comment: but how is that relevant?

Comment: @user13267 then one can deduct where the pictures where taken. You can look up time and date in pictures EXIF metadata (e.g. [here](http://regex.info/exif.cgi)). Do you remember origin and destination (or flight code)? And please add all of these into your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38175/discussion-between-howdedo-and-user13267).

Comment: It's the mountain with the flag on top you see near the horizon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the first, second and 4th image show a large, unforested area with a distinctly differently colored patch. this appears to match the Manpur region on Nasa satellite maps of Nepal (the yellow area circled below), although it also could match the kathmandu region (yellow dots):

[image]

Mount Everest lies in the orange circle. I've tried to match that area to the image:

[image]

My best guess is that Mount Everest lies in the orange circle. this seems to match the general topography of the Mount Everest area: really high mountains surrounding a valley where the mountains taper off slowly. In addition, on the second image, you can almost see what looks like the Annapurna pass between Nepal and Tibet straight ahead from the Manpur region, the area where the mountains don't appear to have snow.

This is only a rough estimate, but to the extent of my knowledge of the region, I think it's the most likely candidate. If the area with the differently colored patch is actually the Kathmandu capital region, the orange dotted mountains are a more likely candidate for Mount Everest. I do not know enough about Nepal to be sure of either claim.